# Unable to change Python text command in optionMenu changeCommand function

Tags: python, maya

I’ve created a UI that has a drop-down list and a button.  I’m trying to add an error message if the button is clicked but nothing has been selected in the drop-down list. I added the error message in the button click function and it works perfectly.  My problem occurs when I try to clear/hide the message in the change command function.  I get the error ‘Too many children in layout”.  I read where layout elements needed to include the parent so I made sure everything was parented.  I tried both setParent and the parent attribute of the element, but it didn't make a difference.  I tried changing the number of columns on the errRowLayout to 2.  That got rid of the layout error, but it didn’t clear my message.  I’ve also discovered that the code will work in one or the other of the functions, but not in both.  I’ve been banging my head against the wall all afternoon trying to figure this out.  I’m sure it’s probably something very simple that I’ve overlooked.

These are the pertinent lines of code.

```
# this is called from another function
def createCustom(self):
    self.characterOptionMenu = pm.optionMenu('characterOptionMenu',  w=self.windowWidth, label=' Choose a Character:', changeCommand=self.item_change, parent=self.mainLayout)      
    self.errRowLayout = pm.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=1, columnWidth=[1, self.windowWidth], columnAlign=[1, 'center'], parent=self.mainLayout)
    self.buttonRowLayout = pm.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=1, width=self.windowWidth, parent=self.mainLayout)
    pm.button("Setup Character", w=self.windowWidth, h=30, command=self.setup_button_click, parent=self.buttonRowLayout)I 

def setup_button_click(self, *args):
    selectedCharacter = pm.optionMenu(self.characterOptionMenu, q=True, value=True)

    if selectedCharacter == ' ':
        # create the error message
        # this statement works
        pm.text(label='Character cannot be blank.', visible=True, backgroundColor=[250, 128, 114], font='boldLabelFont', width=self.windowWidth, parent=self.errRowLayout)
        return

def item_change(self, *args):
    selectedCharacter = pm.optionMenu(self.characterOptionMenu, q=True, value=True)
    # this statement gives me the layout error 
    pm.text(label='', visible=False, parent=self.errRowLayout)
```

All help is greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are *creating* a new text label. In setup_button_click() you already created one text label, then you try to create another with the same parent. That should explain the error.

See the documentation on:

http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/commandspython/text.html

You should probably try to get the full path name of your text label control, then call text() with edit=true.

Comment: Thanks, @Icyvapor.  I see what you're saying.  I was trying to update that text label rather than create another one.  With that in mind, I tried assigning the text label to a variable in the setup_button_click function.  Then I set the visible attribute of that variable to False in the item_change function.  Changing the attribute didn't hide the error message though.  Do I need to refresh something in order for the new value of the visible attribute to be recognized?